# SystemParametersInfo не меняет обои

Tags: c++, winapi

`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)"D:/1.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);`
Пишу так, возвращает 1, обои не меняются. Фотография точно существует

Comment: ¿А если так `"D:\\1.png"`?

Comment: тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

В описании параметра `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` [читаем](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa):

> Retrieves the full path of the ***bitmap file*** for the desktop wallpaper

Т.е. передавайте в функцию имя `.bmp`-файла, и все у вас получится...

Comment: Не работает, теперь файл .bmp, но ничего не проиходит

Comment: Не верю, потому что сам этим пользуюсь :) Единственная непринципиальная разница — я использую `SPIF_SENDCHANGE`. Проверьте, точно ли там формат файла Windows BMP, правильно ли передан путь etc etc...

Comment: Я смотрю что у меня все такие подобные функции не работают, стянул с сайта майков код примера, там где увеличивается сенса, слово в слово скопировал, оно тоже на работает

Comment: Ну тут уж ничего сказать не могу :( С этой установкой обоев — в свое время (чтоб не соврать, еще XP) я начинал с попытки передать JPG, потом разобрался, передал BMP, и все встало на свои места...

Comment: Иногда сетает черный экран, то есть что-то происходит, не неправильно, может потому что у меня 2 монитора? Я не нашел инфу чтобы отдельно на каждый монитор ставить

Comment: Посмотрите тут — https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cQHW9S3JpG5SvXx2sUN_ylm_rYI3aqA6?usp=sharing — простейшая программка, работающая у меня. Да, путь к файлу вы же указывали полный? Иначе он ищет файл в системном каталоге. Попробуйте посмотреть, скомпилировать, запустить. bmp должен лежать вместе с exe в одном каталоге...

Comment: Я разобрался, точнее мне помогли. То что я использую SystemParametersInfo - это процедура. И она требует чтобы не было define UNICODE. Для простоты созданы функции SystemParametersInfoA  - аски, SystemParametersInfoW - юникод

Comment: Она не требует, просто вызов SystemParametersInfo вызывает либо ту, либо другую в зависимости от настроек использования Unicode...